# Is embedding of fonts in wpf application will save from corrupted font cache?

Tags: wpf, caching, fonts

Recently I had corrupted font cache. I fixed it by removal of cache file and restarting of Wpf font cache service. Also I updated my outdated driver.

However there're lot's of users on customer side without administrative rights and there're no way to upgrade their pretty old drivers of videocards.

Could you say me what if i embed all fonts application use in application resources - will it help those guys to not relay on Font Cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually answer is simple: Reboot is needed after upgrading video card drivers.

During reboot if drivers where upgraded, font cache will be reseted.

It this doesn't help user should ask administrator to clean up font cache data as it described here: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937135

Embedding of fonts is bad.